# In-app-purchase for OS X, using AIR

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air, in-app-purchase

Is there a library for working with iap(and other Apple features like push-notification, GameCenter) in OS X, using Adobe AIR?

I found a few free examples for iOS using AIR(and for OS X, using Objective-C), but it seems they are not compatible with OS X.

Comment: Github has air for ios code.  Googling "github air for ios in-app purchases" gets a bunch of results.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: If Mac IAPs work using StoreKit, then should the iOS ANEs work?

Comment: That is the problem. iOS ANEs works only with iOS, not OS X. I think, the only way is to make my own ANE, to work with OS X.

Comment: You should have separate versions of your app for mobile and desktop.  They should share everything except code unique to the device like touch events/mouse events and the stuff you're talking about.